# inheritance and polymorphism implementation in java

Tags: java

i was trying out programs to implement inheritance and polymorphism
and i tried this one program 
but the problem with this program is that
every time i compile this message pops

Compilation Errors -

```
/tmp/scodhvest/1471759912752_aishu.m11@gmail.com/Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
^
symbol: class BufferedReader
location: class Main
/tmp/scodhvest/1471759912752_aishu.m11@gmail.com/Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
^
symbol: class BufferedReader
location: class Main
/tmp/scodhvest/1471759912752_aishu.m11@gmail.com/Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
^
symbol: class InputStreamReader
location: class Main
3 errors
```

this is the main class

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int type,n;
System.out.println("Enter the number of transactions");
n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
Account[] ac=new Account[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    Account a=new Account();
System.out.println("Enter the account number");
a.setAccountNumber(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter the holder name");
a.setHolderName(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter the email address");
a.setEmail(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter the secret code");
a.setSecretCode(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter the number of debits");
a.setNumberOfDebits(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
System.out.println("Enter the number of credits");
a.setNumberOfCredits(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
ac[i]=a;
}
System.out.println("1)Generate Statement from account number\n"
        + "2)Generate Statement from secretcode and email\n"
        + "Enter your choice");
type=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
if(type>2||type<1){
    System.out.println("Invalid");
    System.exit(0);
}
switch(type){
case 1: 
    System.out.println("Enter the account number");
    Account account=new Account().generateStatement(ac,br.readLine());
    if(account==null)
        System.out.println("No account found from given match");
    else{
        System.out.println("Account Number :      "+account.getAccountNumber()+"\n"
                + "Holder Name : "+account.getHolderName()+"\n"
                + "Number of Debits : "+account.getNumberOfDebits()+"\n"
                + "Number of Credits : "+account.getNumberOfCredits());
    }
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println("Enter the secret code");
    String code=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the email address");
    Account accnt=new Account().generateStatement(ac,code,br.readLine());
    if(accnt==null)
        System.out.println("No account found from given match");
    else{
        System.out.println("Account Number : "+accnt.getAccountNumber()+"\n"
                + "Holder Name : "+accnt.getHolderName()+"\n"
                + "Number of Debits : "+accnt.getNumberOfDebits()+"\n"
                + "Number of Credits : "+accnt.getNumberOfCredits());
    }
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}

}
}
```

Comment: You didn't import `BufferedReader` nor `InputStreamReader`

Comment: Have you imported `BufferReader` and `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: oops!! noi will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to import BufferedReader. Before that don't forget to include BufferedReader jar

Comment: @joejoe Request to please mark the answer as correct whichever solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to import the classes before using them. So these lines should come before your coding.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

Your implementation doesn't implement inheritance or polymorphism. First you must understand the concept of inheritance and polymorphism before implement it. Check these tutorials
[Inheritance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm), [Polymophism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)